# In React Native FlatList, what is a batch of items?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

In the section of the docs on [optimization](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#use-keyextractor-or-key) for React Native FlatList, I'm reading about the `maxToRenderPerBatch` prop, and it says `It is a VirtualizedList prop that can be passed through FlatList. This controls the amount of items rendered per batch, which is the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll`.

I can't picture what `the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll` means. For example, let's say I have a list of 100 items. My understanding is that if I don't set `initialNumToRender`, it will automatically render all 100 items (even though they don't all fit on that screen). If I *do* set `initialNumToRender`, say to 10, it will initially render only the first 10.

Then say I set `maxToRenderPerBatch` to 10 and I do a scroll gesture that would reveal 3 more items. What is `the next chunk of items rendered`? Is it 10 or is it 3? And if I don't set `maxToRenderPerBatch`, would it just "lazy-load" one item at a time as each one comes into view?

Comment: `initialNumToRender` is 10 by default

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

Answer (score 0):

Default value of maxToRenderPerBatch is 10: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#maxtorenderperbatch

> maxToRenderPerBatch Type  Default Number  10
>
> It is a VirtualizedList prop that can be passed through FlatList. This
> controls the amount of items rendered per batch, which is the next
> chunk of items rendered on every scroll.
>
> Pros: Setting a bigger number means less visual blank areas when
> scrolling (increases the fill rate).
>
> Cons: More items per batch means longer periods of JavaScript
> execution potentially blocking other event processing, like presses,
> hurting responsiveness.

The bigger the number the smoother the scroll
The smaller the number, the fewer resources are used

initialNumToRender will only matter the first, while maxToRenderPerBatch will be relevant every time the user scrolls.

You can just use the default values if there are no specific requirements. It will be fine in 90% of cases.